# Accessing a field on json data. react native

Tags: react-native

How do I access "courseDesc" in "course_details". I'm making a react native app with laravel as a backend. I'll already done alot of research and I almost got it working but I get JSON Parse error Unrecognize token '<' in my react native code.

```
[
{
  id: 61987,
  active_lesson: "1",
  start_date: "2018-05-09",
  due_date: "2018-05-23",
  grade: "Fail",
  created_at: "2018-05-09 12:59:47",
  updated_at: "2018-09-19 07:12:40",
  course_details: {
    id: 573,
    company_id: null,
    courseDesc: null,
    questionDisplay: "single",
  }
},
{
  id: 61988,
  active_lesson: "1",
  start_date: "2018-05-09",
  due_date: "2018-05-23",
  grade: "Not Yet Taken",
  created_at: "2018-05-09 12:59:47",
  updated_at: "2018-05-09 12:59:47",
  course_details: null
},....
```

This is my react native code:

```
fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost/elearning/public/api/courses');
    const json = await response.json();
    this.setState({data: json.course_details});
}

render() {

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
                data={this.state.data}
                keyExtractor={(x, i) => i}
                renderItem={({ item }) =>
                    <Text>
                        {'${item.courseDesc}'}
                    </Text>}
            />
        </View>
        );

  }
```

this is my PHP code:

```
echo $result->toJson(JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

It's been 2 days I've been working on this, I really need help. I promise to help stackoverflow and give back to new programmers.

[image]

Comment: can u please do console.log(json) and provide it?

Comment: Please check your php code it should return json.

Comment: just like that will work
 ``` $data['dept'] = DB::select('SELECT * FROM dept');
        return json_encode($data); ```

Comment: @SathvikNasani I added the console picture in the post.

Comment: @reactNative_dev_kiki from backend you need to send json object

Comment: @reactNative_dev_kiki: Have you tried what i suggested?

Comment: I already use JSON.stringify function but it doesn't work, I'm using laravel as a back end to my react native.

Comment: what do you mean by it doesnt work, can you supply some code/debug-output in your question?

Comment: Could it be that your request returns HTML instead of a JSON and when you try to parse it, the first char would be <, which is already invalid for a JSON string.

Answer (score 1):

Your backend supplies a nested object literal, not a valid json object..

Here's the laravel article on serialization -> [Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-serialization)

what you need to achieve is getting a valid json like:

```
{
    "id": "61987",
    "active_lesson": "1",
    "start_date": "2018-05-09",
    "due_date": "2018-05-23",
    "grade": "Fail",
    "created_at": "2018-05-09 12:59:47",
    "updated_at": "2018-09-19 07:12:40",
    "course_details": {
    "id": 573,
    "company_id": null,
    "courseDesc": null,
    "questionDisplay": "single"
    }
}
```

You can check the validity of your objects by using any of the online validators depending on the draft -> [link](https://jsonlint.com/).

I would also suggest you take a closer look at the [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method.

From W3C:

> The JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string, optionally replacing values if a replacer function is specified or optionally including only the specified properties if a replacer array is specified.

Consider using json_encode() [method](https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_json_php.asp) in your php backend.

toJson info:

> Json Serializer for PHP. This is a library to serialize PHP variables in JSON format. It is similar of the serialize() function in PHP, but the output is a string JSON encoded. You can also unserialize the JSON generated by this tool and have you PHP content back.

Here is a good [article](https://nitschinger.at/Handling-JSON-like-a-boss-in-PHP/) on how to handle Json in your php-backend - maybe worth a read.

**EDIT:**

Could it be that your request returns HTML instead of a JSON and when you try to parse it, the first char would be <, which is already invalid for a JSON string.